# How to backup a database in c# after connection is established

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I've written code to access and display all databases within a given server. Now I'm trying to actually perform the backup processes and have the file saved to my desktop for now. However, when it gets to the `SQLBackup()` I get a

> SqlException: Cannot open backup device.

I've tried changing the file path to a different location. Specifying the filetype as `.bak`. Changed it to the server name itself, but I keep getting the same error.

```
    public static void Backup(string dbName, string connString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbName)) //check if a database name has been entered
        {
            WriteLine("Database name cannot be blank. Enter a Database to back up");
        }
        else
        { 
            SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(objconnection.DataSource.ToString());
            Server server = new Server(con);
            Backup source = new Backup();
            source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            source.Database = dbName;
            BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\", DeviceType.File);
            source.Devices.Add(destination);

            source.SqlBackup(server);
        }
    }
```

If this runs correctly I should have a backup file of the database on my desktop.

Comment: Maybe its because you're not specifying a file and just a folder as the save path.

Comment: It is better to just De-Attach the database and make copy of the MDF file, then reattach.

Comment: @jdweng - why?  and if you do do that, you would also need the LDF in order to restore.

Comment: Does the SQL user have access to the file system?  The error suggests that it does not.

Comment: Deattach doesn't require any options nor admin to privileges.  We ran into a lot of issues with privileges archiving and found the de-attach/attach much easier.  You have option of archiving logs and reattach.  Also much quicker.  Archiving take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my first parameter in the backupdeviceitem. Changing that to dbname (or any other name) fixed the issue.